# Angular serve dynamic asset

Tags: angular

Is it possible to serve a dynamic asset?

For example, can I have `http://example.com/dynamic.js` serve a JavaScript file that is dynamically generated by Angular instead of coming from `assets`?

I'm trying to understand how [Angular's Service Worker](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) is able to serve its `/ngsw-worker.js` file. Is there just some unobtainable magic in setting `"serviceWorker": true` in the `.angular-cli.json`?

---

Edit 2018-03-25:

I'm guessing the answer is "no, it's not possible, and an exception was made for Angular's Service Worker in a way that is not reusable by others." But please correct or confirm me in answers and comments.

I suppose that if I *really* needed to serve up dynamically-generated assets, then I could just switch to Angular Universal. Then I'd be able to have Angular do its normal thing, and use Express web server on the backend to dynamically-generate things.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is for during development - right?

Comment: Do you want to import the JavaScript file in the .angular-cli.json file? Or you want to dynamically inject it in the specific component typescript file?

Comment: @mehany Not necessarily. If this is possible it would be interesting to be able to hook into Angular's dependency injection system or something like that. But I don't really have a goal in mind except to learn how something like Angular's Service Worker is able to do this.

Comment: @MeetDave Not the former: the way Angular Service Worker configures its JavaScript file name is at runtime with a module setting. Possibly the latter but not necessarily. I understand how to get Angular's router to serve up a specific component for a given URL, but that doesn't seem to fit the bill. For example, I don't see a way to change the `content-type` response header to `application/javascript` for a particular route. It also doesn't seem possible to service a route without the rendered result including the `index.html` template.

Comment: @MeetDave One possible use case, for example, if this is possible, is to implement a custom service worker. My understanding of how that works is you tell the browser to register a JavaScript file located at a particular URL. Then the browser makes an HTTP request for that file and loads it and expects it to behave a certain way. The "telling the browser to register something" part can happen within a component--it's just a matter of doing [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#register_a_service_worker). But how could I get Angular to service the URL?